# Fix the array type and method error in my java classes, really lost at how to fix the error

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, compiler-errors, runtime-error

I have the following error when I run my parser program,

```
Error: Main method not found in class TfIdfMain, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

Also in my main method, there is a error like this, but I already created the parserfile error in parser class,

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Default constructor cannot handle exception type IOException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit 
     constructor
    - Default constructor cannot handle exception type FileNotFoundException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an 
     explicit constructor
```

Also in my parser class, there is an error around the array list line, it says array cannot be resolved, how should I fix this?　Create a new variable.

Here are my two main classes involved the errors:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
public class TfIdfMain {

    }
   // public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
   //     DocumentParser dp = new DocumentParser();
   //     dp.parseFiles("C:\\Users\\Sarah\\Documents");
   //     dp.getCosineMatrix(); 
   // }
  }
}
```

My document parser class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class DocumentParser {

    private void doSomething(){
            String text = "Professor, engineering, data, mining, research";
            StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(text);
            String word[] = new String[10];
            String unique[] = new String[10];
            String x;
            int count = -1;
            while (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
                count++;
                x = str.nextToken();

            if (f.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
                in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String s = null;
                while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(s);
                }
                String[] tokenizedTerms = sb.toString().replaceAll("[\\W&&[^\\s]]", "").split("\\W+");   //to get individual terms
                for (String term : tokenizedTerms) {
                    if (!allTerms.contains(term)) {  
                        allTerms.add(term);
                    }
                }
                termsDocsArray.add(tokenizedTerms);
            }
        }

    }

    public void tfIdfCalculator() {
        double tf; 
        double idf; 
        double tfidf;       
        for (String[] docTermsArray : termsDocsArray) {
            double[] tfidfvectors = new double[allTerms.size()];
            int count = 0;
            for (String terms : allTerms) {
                tf = new TfIdf().getTf(docTermsArray, terms);
                idf = new TfIdf().idfCalculation(termsDocsArray, terms);
                tfidf = tf * idf;
                tfidfvectors[count] = tfidf;
                count++;
            }
            tfidfDocsVector.add(tfidfvectors);      
        }
    }
    public void getCosineMatrix() {
        for (int i = 0; i < tfidfDocsVector.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tfidfDocsVector.size(); j++) {
                System.out.println("between " + i + " and " + j + "  =  "
                                   + new CosineSimilarity().getCosine
                                       (
                                         tfidfDocsVector.get(i), 
                                         tfidfDocsVector.get(j)
                                       )
                                  );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read your error-message and then check your code:

`Error: Main method not found in class TfIdfMain, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)`

what could be the problem? the main-method was not found. In your code it is commented out.

And in your `TfIdfMain`-class: 
at least your for-loop has to be in a method / constructor.
Do something like

```
public class TfIdfMain
    public TfIdfMain(){
        for(String file : files) {
            DocumentParser dp = new DocumentParser();
            dp.parseFiles(file);
            dp.getCosineMatrix();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, I emailed you. you can delete your email comment now.

Answer (score 1):

your main method is commented out, that is why it isn't found by the compiler.
The for loop isn't inside a method and only in the class body. This is wrong in java.
The error messages from the compiler tell you exactly what to do, you have to provide an special constructor which can handle the exceptions.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been working on this code for hours now! Since I can't post another question for another hour and I don't know if you will be on later. I'm working hard trying to get this code to work. Can I email you? My email is firstjavapython on gmail, it's a temporary acount, so you won't have worry about privacy. Please considering help me! I really need your help!